# jquery call button clicking event not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with several rows:

```
<table id="sellInvoiceDetailTable_new">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-guid="0ca63dae-c06c-4abc-8635-71d164a05a5f">
            <td data-name="ValueAfterDiscount"></td>
            <td data-name="Total"></td>
            <td data-name="_operations">
                <span><button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</button></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-guid="0ca63dae-c06c-4abc-8635-71d164a05a5f">
            <td data-name="ValueAfterDiscount"></td>
            <td data-name="Total"></td>
            <td data-name="_operations">
                <span><button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</button></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

What I want is when clicking on buttons in the rows, call a function that is called inside setTimeOut. So I wrote below Jquery code:

```
$('#sellInvoiceDetailTable_new').children('tbody').children('tr')
    .children("td[data-name='_operations']").find('button').click(setTimeout(function() {
        setRowNo();
    }, 500));
```

I have tried below code too:

```
 $('#sellInvoiceDetailTable_new').find("td[data-name=_operations]")
 .find('button').click(setTimeout(function()
 {
    setRowNo();
 }, 500));
```

But still the event is not being called.

Comment: Why do you need `setTimeout`? What exactly you want?

Comment: Buttons in rows,are for removing that row and after deleted ,rows must be sort by function named "setRowNo".

Comment: `.click(function() { setTimeout(function () { setRowNo(); }, 500); });`

Comment: You need to pass a function definition to the click event, by calling `setTimeout()` (note the `()`) you are returning the *result* of the setTimeout() call.

Comment: You mean that the selector is true and type of function call is false???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want `setRowNo` to be called 0.5 seconds after the button is clicked?

The problem is that you're calling the `setTimeout` which returns a unique ID for the timeout, and that is what you are passing to the `click()`.

What you need to do is wrap that `setTimeout` within an anonymous function...

```
.click(function() { setTimeout(...) })
```

Also, because `setRowNo` has no parameters, you can also shorten the following...

```
setTimeout(function() { setRowNo(); }, 500)
```

... to the following...

```
setTimeout(setRowNo, 500);
```

So your line becomes...

```
$('#sellInvoiceDetailTable_new').children('tbody').children('tr')
  .children("td[data-name='_operations']").find('button').click(function()
  { 
    setTimeout(setRowNo, 500)
  });
```

---

You can also reduce the processing jQuery has to do by combining your selector like this...

```
$('#sellInvoiceDetailTable_new td[data-name="_operations"] button').click(function()
{
  setTimeout(setRowNo, 500)
});
```

---

```js
$('#sellInvoiceDetailTable_new td[data-name="_operations"] button').click(function() { setTimeout(setRowNo, 500) });

var _temp = 0;
function setRowNo() {
  console.log(++_temp);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sellInvoiceDetailTable_new">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-guid="0ca63dae-c06c-4abc-8635-71d164a05a5f">
            <td data-name="ValueAfterDiscount"></td>
            <td data-name="Total"></td>
            <td data-name="_operations">
                <span><button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</button></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-guid="0ca63dae-c06c-4abc-8635-71d164a05a5f">
            <td data-name="ValueAfterDiscount"></td>
            <td data-name="Total"></td>
            <td data-name="_operations">
                <span><button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</button></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes  That's true..Thanks for help